# MacPorts Invalid Entry

Tags: macos, osx-lion, macports, sqlite

I am stuck upgrading my MacPorts. I seem to have a registry issue. I filed a ticket [here](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/34482). When I do `sudo port upgrade outdated` I get these errors:

```
DEBUG: Executing org.macports.uninstall (iso-codes)
--->  Unable to uninstall iso-codes @3.34_0, the following ports depend on it:
Error: org.macports.uninstall for port iso-codes returned: an invalid entry was passed
DEBUG: Error code: registry::invalid
DEBUG: Backtrace: an invalid entry was passed
    while executing
"$depport name"
    (procedure "registry::check_dependents" line 19)
    invoked from within
"registry::check_dependents $port ${uninstall.force} "uninstall""
    (procedure "registry_uninstall::uninstall" line 83)
    invoked from within
"registry_uninstall $subport $version $revision $portvariants [array get user_options]"
    (procedure "portuninstall::uninstall_main" line 3)
    invoked from within
"$procedure $targetname"
Warning: targets not executed for iso-codes: org.macports.uninstall
Please see the log file for port iso-codes for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_registry_portfiles_iso-codes_3.34_0/iso-codes/main.log
DEBUG: an invalid entry was passed
    while executing
"$depport name"
    (procedure "registry::check_dependents" line 19)
    invoked from within
"registry::check_dependents $port ${uninstall.force} "uninstall""
    (procedure "registry_uninstall::uninstall" line 83)
Warning: Failed to execute portfile from registry for iso-codes @3.34_0
--->  Unable to uninstall iso-codes @3.34_0, the following ports depend on it:
DEBUG: an invalid entry was passed
    while executing
"$depport name"
    (procedure "registry::check_dependents" line 19)
    invoked from within
"registry::check_dependents $port ${uninstall.force} "uninstall""
    (procedure "registry_uninstall::uninstall" line 83)
    invoked from within
"registry_uninstall::uninstall $newname $version_in_tree $revision_in_tree $portinfo(canonical_active_variants) [array get options]"
Error: Uninstall iso-codes 3.34_0 failed: an invalid entry was passed
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
```

Another MacPorts user had the same issue and it seems he did not find an answer. It seems to be an error related to the registry - sqlite database .I have been trying to find out how I can solve this issue. I have been unsuccessful. Without a fix I cannot move onEven uninstalling all ports to do a new clean installation does not work.

How can I

- fix this issue
- if it cannot be fixed reinstall MacPorts when uninstalling ports is impossible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was resolved thanks to people at MacPorts. See track ticket [here](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/34482). There was an issue with the MacPorts registry. Somehow the SQLite database had some rogue dependency leftovers that had to be removed.I ran the sqlite query

```
sqlite> UPDATE dependencies SET id = 2323 WHERE id = 1407;
```

to replace the id of the missing port in the database with the id used by pkgconfig. It worked like a charm. I then could do

```
sudo upgrade outdated
```

again and continue upgrading all my outdated ports and repair the broken ones. All good now!

Answer (score 3):

A digest of the solution proposed at [uninstall failure: "an invalid entry was passed"](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/34482):

Step 1: Open the Macports registry with `sqlite3`:

```
sudo sqlite3 /opt/local/var/macports/registry
```

Step 2: Find the problematic ports:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM dependencies WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM ports);
618|apr|
618|expat|
618|libiconv|
618|db46|
618|sqlite3|
```

Step 3: Remove the offending rows:

```
DELETE FROM dependencies WHERE id = 618;
DELETE FROM files WHERE id = 618;
```

Step 4: Fix your instalation

```
sudo port selfupdate 
sudo port upgrade outdated
```

Note that the `id` varies per installation!